# PHP foreach multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Hi there I have been at a loss with the `foreach` loop. What I'm trying to do is have multiple arrays in a `foreach` loop.

All I can find on the Internet is how to get a single value out of the arrays. I managed to get two working with:

```
foreach (array_combine($slides, $headers) as $slide => $header)
```

But that's limited to only two arrays. I just want list after list for more than two arrays.

Comment: Give an example of the arrays that you have and what you want the corresponding output to be.

Answer (score 2):

Since `array_combine` is working for you with two arrays, that means you want the elements at the same position, so you can use the same key:

```
foreach ($slides as $key => $slide) {
   echo $slide;
   echo $headers[$key];
   echo $another[$key];
   //etc...
}
```

If the keys may not match then re-index before the loop:

```
$slides  = array_values($slides);
$headers = array_values($headers);
$another = array_values($another);
```

You will run into issues if the arrays aren't the same length so you might check:

```
if(isset($headers[$key])) { echo $headers[$key]; }
```

Another way might be to map them into a multi-dimensional array grouped one from each in a sub-array. The integer index for `$values` matches the order of the arrays in `array_map`:

```
foreach(array_map(null, $slides, $headers, $another) as $values) {
    echo $values[0];
    echo $values[1];
    echo $values[2];
}
```

Or assign the array values to variables:

```
foreach(array_map(null, $slides, $headers, $another) as $values) {
    list($s, $h, $a) = $values;
    echo $s;
    echo $h;
    echo $a;
}
```